# In Loopback.js, how to query on embedded models?

Tags: loopbackjs

I'm using MongoDB connector and have a Considerate and Discussion model setup like this:

model-config.json:

```
{
    "Considerate": {"dataSource": "db"},
    "Discussion": {"dataSource": "transient"}
}
```

considerate.json:

```
{
    "name": "Considerate",
    "base": "PersistedModel",
    "relations": {
        "discussion": {"type": "embedsOne", "model": "Discussion"}
    }
}
```

discussion.json:

```
{
    "name": "Discussion",
    "base": "Model",
    "properties": {
        "name": {"type": "string"}
        },
        "relations": {
            "considerate": {"type": "belongsTo", "model": "Considerate"}
        }
    }
}
```

How can I query for Considerates based on Discussion's properties? For example, something like this:

`Considerate.find({where: {'discussion.name': 'snow white'}})`

Inspecting Mongo persisted data, I see that in each Considerate document, there's a `_discussion` property. Consequently, `Considerate.find({where: {'_discussion.name': 'snow white'}})` works. However, this is undocumented and wondering if there is a documented/reliable way to to this.

Comment: This is the right way. Unfortunately loopback docs is poor and has examples for trivial cases

Comment: To confirm, using the `_` is correct? `Considerate.find({where: {'_discussion.name': 'snow white'}})`. That definitely feels hacky.

Comment: You can define it yourself. `"discussion": {"type": "embedsOne", "model": "Discussion", "property": "my_disc"}`. If you don't define `property` then the loopback set the property by adding `_` before relation name

Comment: Ah, i see, thank you @EbrahimPasbani

Answer (score 0):

You can use the filters in the REST APIs wherever you want data from your relations. Eg: `[include][relationName]`

I think you can also pass data to the fields here.

https://docs.strongloop.com/display/public/LB/Where+filter

This might help you too
https://github.com/strongloop/loopback/issues/517